# 0x1 issue in windows task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

I am running a bat file which will delete the files or folders older than 14 days from the today's date , when i am testing it in local folders it is executing fine, but when i am trying to delete the files or folders from the network drive. I am getting error 0x1. Could some one help me out on this. I am trying this from last 2 weeks still didnt find any solution. :(

Also to mention i have tried lot of ways like giving the start in parameter, run with super privileges , run whether the user is logged on or not. All this i have tried but no resolution.

Note: When run when the user is logged in is checked , the task run successfully and i get result 0x0, but i need to run on whether user is logged on or not.

Below is my script if you find any issue or required modification let me know. I am new to this.

```
%1
%2
%3
%4
forfiles -p %1 -s -m *.* /D -%2 /C "cmd /c del @path"
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %1 /A:D /B /S ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d" 2>NUL >NUL
forfiles -p %3 -s -m *.* /D -%2 /C "cmd /c del @path"
forfiles -p %4 -s -m *.* /D -%2 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

%1 - %4 are the parameters i am passing throung the arguments in the task scheduler

Addition- Also when i execute my script the files which are older then specific date are getting deleted(note: this works only when option selected as "Run user is logged on") but still it shows 0x1 error. looks like might script is wrong :(

Comment: Look on the task history tab for clues.

Comment: Have you got the "Logon as Batch" Group Policy enabled for this user?

Comment: @DavidPostill - task history tab shows nothing , it shows task esecuted and then task completed.

Comment: How are you referencing the network drives? If you are using mapped drive letters, these are valid only for users and will not be visible in a system session, and you will need to use the full network URL. While testing, append standard output and error to a log file in order to see any errors that the command generates.

Comment: @Harvey- yes the the policy is enable for the user. I am using service account which have full permission.

Comment: @AFH - yes i am using mapped drive letters

Comment: @Nik - Let me know what happens when you try my suggestions.

Comment: @AFH - "While testing, append standard output and error to a log file in order to see any errors that the command generates" , can you please guide me where i can add this ? so can generate log.. apologies i am new to this and didn't know where to add all those command/code. thanks AFH

Comment: If you add `>>output.log 2>&1` to each of the commands, all of the output will be redirected (remove the current redirections from the `rd` command). If you aren't sure which output came from which command, you can use separate files for each command. If you rerun the script, remember to clear the output first.

Comment: @AFH - hi AFH, the problem with deleting the file in share drive is solved now, i had use net use command and then try to delete it and it works fine, it was not working when the drives are mapped. However regarding the log file generation i am still getting issue.

Comment: I want to generate logs which have details of the files/folders which get deleted via script, i am able to generate a log file but its blank. 
Below is my sample script.   **echo ON
  set logfile="E:\Housekeeping\delete.log"
  net use M: networkdrive
  net use N: networkdrive

  forfiles -p "M:\STG\testdtemp" -s -m *.* /D -0 /C "cmd /c >> %logfile% del @path"
  forfiles -p "samplepath" -s -m *.* /D -0 /C "cmd /c del @path >> %logfile%" 

  net use M: /delete
  net use N: /delete**

Comment: You haven't redirected standard error, where error messages go, while `del` by default does not log successful deletions. Do you get a log if you launch the command manually?